# copying images from folder to another folder based on its name in a list

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to copy all the images mentioned in the list to the destination folder.
I tried this code but nothing happend.

```
Original_folder_Path = 'directory'
Destination_folder_path = 'directory'
List = [['100.jpg',1], ['101.jpg',0],['102.jpg',0],['103.jpg',1]]
the Original folder has all the images named as '100.jpg' till '500.jpg'




import shutil
import os 

Original_folder_Path = 'directory'
Destination_folder_path = 'directory'
List = [['100.jpg',1], ['101.jpg',0],['102.jpg',0],['103.jpg',1]]

for files in glob.iglob(os.path.join(Original_folder_Path ,"*.jpg")):
    
    if '{files}.jpg' in List:
        
        shutil.copy(files, Destination_folder_path )
```

Comment: Your list is a list of lists. Not clear what you are trying to do. What are the numbers next file names.

Comment: the number next to the file name is the label, don't worry about the label, i just wanna find the images in list and copy them from the original folder and put them in the destination folder

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import shutil
import os, glob

path = 'source_directory/'
Destination_folder_path = 'destination_directory/'
yourList = [['100.jpg',1], ['101.jpg',0],['102.jpg',0],['103.jpg',1]]
mylist = []
for values in yourList:
    mylist.append(values[0])

#mylist= ['100.jpg', '101.jpg']
#get all the file into a list.
my_files = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name))] 
#get files ending with .jpg
image_files = [file for file in my_files if file.endswith('.jpg')]

myFilesWithFullPath=[] #make a list of files with fullpath
for item in mylist:
    myFilesWithFullPath.append(path+item)

for file in myFilesWithFullPath:
    shutil.copy(file, Destination_folder_path)
```

Comment: myFilesWithFullPath.append(directory+item)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: it did't work, how to add item to path ?!!

Comment: It works on my macOS file system. You are concatenating str. I can check later again when I have time.

Comment: You are concatenating str. You can check this by putting a print statement such as `print(type(item))` or `print(type(item))`. Both are str on my computer. I suggest you make test directories and debug your code.

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.0

Comment: myList = [['100.jpg',1], ['101.jpg',0],['102.jpg',0],['103.jpg',1]] looks like that , not as yours!!

Comment: You can convert your list to my list. I have added the code. You simply get the first element of the sublist and generate new list.